# Hot Topics in 30 days range

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have over 10k topics in my DB table, and I count page views for each topic on session base and store only **one view/per topic/per user** (session time 24 hrs).

```
ID-----Topic----------------Views
1------Love------------------400
2------Friends---------------203
3------Birthday--------------360
```

Now I want to get hot topics in last 30 days, means I want to get hot topics on bases of page views in last 30 days. I just need a little direction, on how I can achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do this in SQL or C#?  Also, we will need to know what your tables contain (particularly in the way of datestamps) to offer any help.

Comment: I suppose you have another table with the date of the view and a fk pointing to the topic, is that the case?

Comment: Thnaks for quick replies. Currently I have topic published date (smalldatetime) and i think C# way will be fine. What you think? And I also can make new table with FK.

Comment: Do you store the individual view events in their own table? Without that, it's hard to filter by views by time range, if you're just updating a counter on the header row.

Comment: @willaien: Yes currently I am updating views in topics table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to separate into a Topic table and a TopicView table if you want to truly adapt to recent views.  With the current table structure there is no idea of how recent a view is - so if you have a topic spike big-time in week 10 of the year, it may remain #1 on your hot topic list for a very long time (as 'Views' column is cumulative over all-time).

```
CREATE TABLE Topic (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    [Topic] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE TopicView (
    [ViewId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [TopicId] INT NOT NULL,
    [User] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [ViewDate] DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

Now you can check every time a user hits a page if  you have already logged a 'TopicView' for them.  When you want to see what topics are hot, you could execute:

```
DECLARE @maxResults INT = 100  --the maximum number of results we will show
DECLARE @hotTopicViewDays INT = 30 --how recent we want to see hot topic activity
DECLARE @hotTopicViewLimit INT = 300 --what amount of views we consider hot


SELECT TOP (@maxResults)
    T.[Id],
    T.[Topic],
    COUNT(TV.[ViewID]) [Views]
FROM [Topic] T
    JOIN [TopicView] TV
    ON T.[Id] = TV.[TopicId]
WHERE TV.ViewDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -(@hotTopicViewDays), GETDATE())
GROUP BY T.[Id],
    T.[Topic]
HAVING COUNT(TV.[ViewId]) >= @hotTopicViewLimit
```

This is pretty extensible and will allow you to configure:

1. How many results you want to return with @maxResults
2. How recent views need to be to factor into "hot topic" activity with @hotTopicViewDays
3. How much activity is required to consider a topic "hot" with @hotTopicViewLimit

Let me know if there are any questions or if anyone sees an issue with this approach.

Comment: I totally agree that this is the true way to query the most viewed topics however, OP already has 10,000 records for which he will never know the correct date ranges.

Comment: @Chris: I will implement it now, and will post the results soon. Thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: I should point out that the TopicView table can very large, depending on the amount of views. You should keep that in mind and include indexes if necessary, or change the representation in order to group all the daily views in one tuple

Comment: @Troveldom: Yes I know it will be very large over time, but I am adding 1 view per user per 24 hrs for a topic. Site currently have over 20k unique visitors daily according to Google Analytics. Can you please explain some more about one tuple? Thanks

Comment: You can change the definition of TupleView removing the user and adding an integer representing the total amount of views for that date. It is similar to what you had before, but with an entry for each day. You will be recording less data (no user tracking for example, no time visit information) but I think you should keep it in mind in case you have performance issues over time.

Comment: @chris: Sorry for again taking it up, I hope I am not interrupting anything. in your solution `@hotTopicViewLimit` If I don't wanna set the limit, and want to show the top most views first then? Please reply

Comment: Remove `HAVING COUNT(TV.[ViewId]) >= @hotTopicViewLimit`.  That removes the limit.  Add `ORDER BY COUNT(TV.[ViewID]) DESC`.  That should sort by views descending.  Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You already store the views in the database, which is good. You'll also need to have stored the date on which the topic was created.

Provided you have done that, you can write a query *like* this one (I dunno your column names etc.):

```
SELECT *
FROM Topics t
WHERE t.DateAdded >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
ORDER BY t.Views DESC
```

It returns all topics created in the last 30 days, most viewed topics first.

You do not want to load all ten thousand records into memory so, make sure you implement pagination.

Comment: You could SELECT count(*), topic.name with a GROUP BY clause and get the exact data needed.

Comment: It might be worth adding a `Views > x` constraint that is configurable as he has said he wants just the "hot" topics.  Then he'll be able to set what "hot" means.

Comment: Or another option - a `TOP (@postLimit)` addition to the `SELECT`

Comment: @ChrisSchubert Yep. I am not really sure what constitutes "hottest". I _suspect_ websites like Reddit determine hot topics based on views _and_ interactions such as comments and link clicks. That could be quite complicated to write a SO answer on.

Comment: @Petrichor: Thanks for your reply, but I will implement the Chris Schubert solution first. cheers!